# ASP / C# Session Variable - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I'm somewhat new to ASP / C# and I'm having an issue (probably simple) with sessions variables. My project has a Site.Master in which session variables are set under the Page_Load method like so:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if ((Session)["UserID"]==null || (Session)["UserID"].ToString() == "")
        {
            (Session)["UserID"] = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
            SqlDataReader dr = Sprocs.GetPermissionGroups();

            string groupList = "";

            while (dr.Read())
            {
            if (groupList != "")
                    {
                        groupList = groupList + "|" + dr["WG_Group"].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        groupList = dr["WG_Group"].ToString();
                    }
            }
            dr.Close();

            if (groupList != "")
            {
                (Session)["UserGroups"] = groupList;
            }
        }
```

This does work. If I dump out the session variable 'UserGroups' to a label or something within this method, it does display the variable contents correctly.

So, my problem lies within another page (say default.aspx) when I try to access that same session variable. In the Page_Load method of the other page I attempt to do this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string GroupList = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserGroups"].ToString();
            //some code with the variables here
    }
```

This always fails with an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error. Am I trying to get the Session variable wrong? I've tried

```
string GroupList = Session["UserGroups"].ToString();
```

this also errors with the same error.

```
string GroupList = (string)(Session["UserGroups"]);
```

This always returns an empty string.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: do you hit the first page before going to the second page?

Comment: what do you have your session state set to in the web.config?

Comment: The first page should be loading first. The way I understand the site.master and any pages that use it is that the site.master loads first, then the page using it.

as for web.config, under <system.web> I've got   <sessionState mode="InProc"/>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax you are using in your `Page_Load` method I wouldn't have even expected to compile. Regardless, the issue is that you have not set the Session with that key, so it will return `null`. When you call `ToString()` on that null, you get the exception. In your second example:

```
string groupList = (string)(Session["UserGroups"])
```

That is doing a conversion of null to `string`, which results in a null string (thus not causing the exception).

You should be able to rewrite your `Page_Load` implementation like so:

```
string sessionUserId = Session["UserId"] as string;

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionUserId))
{
    Session["UserId"] = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();

    SqlDataReader dr = Sprocs.GetPermissionGroups();

    string groupList = "";

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        if (groupList != "")
        {
            groupList = groupList + "|" + dr["WG_Group"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            groupList = dr["WG_Group"].ToString();
        }
    }
    dr.Close();

    Session["UserGroups"] = groupList;
}
```

Then, when accessing the session variable later, do it like so:

```
 string userGroup = Session["UserGroups"] as string;
```

This is a safe way to attempt the conversion of whatever bucket that is in session into a string. If the key doesnt exist, or the value is not a string, you will get `null`. Otherwise, you will get the string from that hash.

Comment: Alright, that does make sense on why I was getting the error and casting that 'as string' does prevent it from happening.

Though that does raise another question. Not sure how the best way to word it is. So this code above is in say default.aspx which uses Site.Master and it's Page_load to set the variables. If I start on default.aspx then for some reason when I check the session variables in the page_load of default.aspx they are blank. If I navigate to another page and then back they are populated. Does Site.Master load after page_load of default.aspx?

Comment: The master page will execute it's `Page_Load` event before the child page. I'd verify that you are not doing something odd in your master page that would be affecting things. In addition, your child `Page_Load` invokes `HttpContext.Current.Session` instead of `this.Session` - while it should be irrelevant, make sure you are consistent.

Comment: Alright I got things figured out. After doing some testing and reading it does appear that the page_load for the site.master DOES occur AFTER the page_load of default.aspx, which explains what I'm seeing. Moved my session variable code to the Session_Start method in Global.asax and it seems to be working like I want it to. Thanks again for the help!